# Eclipse RCP: InternalPlatform.getDefault().getUserLocation() doesen't return C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, environment-variables, eclipse-rcp

I am currently migrating an Eclipse 3.0 application to 4.4. The user data was and still should be stored in the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\applicationname`

The application is using following code to read the directory:

```
public static String getUserDirectory()
{
  String directory = InternalPlatform.getDefault().getUserLocation().getFile();
  return directory;
}
```

I know the code is deprecated, but following code returns the same:

```
public static String getUserDirectory()
{
    String directory = Platform.getUserLocation().getURL().getFile();
    return directory;
}
```

They both return `C:\Users\username\user` but as I said the user data should be stored at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\applicationname`. Did the behaviour of those methods change?

How can I realize that I store my user data under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\applicationname` and my application can still find the directory?

I know this has to do something with environment-variables which I don't fully understand.

Comment: Probably something to do with the `osgi.user.area` environment variable, but I don't know any more than that.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, you are right. I had to add those three lines to my config.ini manually after exporting
`osgi.instance.area=@user.home/AppData/Roaming/programname/workingDirectory`
`osgi.configuration.area=@user.home/AppData/Roaming/programname/configDirectory`
`osgi.user.area=@user.home/AppData/Roaming/programname`
Sadly you can only set the osgi.configuration.area per VM-parameter in the product configuration file, so I have to add this after the product export before creating the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding three properties in the Configuration tab of my config.ini.product-file:

- osgi.configuration.area =
  @user.home/AppData/Roaming/ApplicationName/...
- osgi.user.area =
  @user.home/AppData/Roaming/ApplicationName/...
- osgi.instance.area  =
  @user.home/AppData/Roaming/ApplicationName

Now my method as stated in my question reads the paths that are configured by those properties and the config.ini file which is generated looks exactly like the one of the old build with Eclipse 3.0.

Comment: I am in the same situation now. Just beware, that the locations shown here are very windows-specific.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a 3.x target platform at hand to compare but `C:\Users\username\user` looks plain wrong.

If you are interested in the details, the constructor of `EquinoxLocations` computes the `userLocation` and adds the literal 'user' the the user's home directory if no default is specified.

Hence, if you start your application with `-user @user.home` or `-Dosgi.user.area=@user.home`, the user location will be set to `C:\Users\username\`. Still not what you are looking for, but at least a sane value.

I think this is a bug in Equinox and recommend to file a bugzilla. If it turns out that there is a good reason for this appraoch the bug entry will still serve as documentation/reasoning.

In the meanwhile you could obtain the home directory on Windows through `System.getenv( "APPDATA" )`. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867022/i-want-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-computers-with-java) it will return the *roaming home directory*.

Comment: Do you know, what happened with that issue? I still see the "user" path postfix.

Comment: Probably nothing happened. The OP seem to not have filed a bug (or didn't reference it here). Did you search the Eclipse bugzilla?

Comment: At least there are no bugs containing getUserLocation (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=getUserLocation)